# Firebase Cloud Functions silent push notification to iOS

Tags: firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send silent push notification to iOS from could functions, but cannot receive any message.
Here is my payload

```
const payload = {
    apns: {
        "headers":{
            "apns-priority":"5",
            "apns-push-type":"background"
        },
        payload: {
            aps: {
                "content-available": 1,
                "priority": "high"
            }
        }
    },
    data: {
        orderId: "123",
        orderStatus: "done"
    },
    token: "fcm_Token_Value_Here"
}
await admin.messaging().send(payload)
```

Any suggestions what could be the issue?

Comment: The question is a bit vague. How are receiving the notifications? In an app you coded? Including that code would be useful. How are you initiating the notification? We really need some details to be able to help. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

After short investigation with firebase docs the answer is following:

```
const payload = {
    apns: {
        payload: {
            aps: {
                "contentAvailable": true
            }
        }
    },
    data: {
        orderId: "123",
        orderStatus: "done"
    },
    token: "fcm_Token_Value_Here"
}
```

Removed headers part, changed "content-available": 1 to "contentAvailable": true, and removed "priority": "high".